# Aptana Studio 3 not working with RailsInstaller 2.0.1

Tags: aptana

When Aptana creates a new Rails project, the following message comes:

```
sh: /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rails: C:/Projects/railsinstaller/stage/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

In RailsInstaller ruby/bin folder there´s a bat file for rails (Rails.bat) that contains:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/Projects/railsinstaller/stage/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rails" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

A new Rails project can be created without Aptana, but using it or types rails in its terminal produces the error.

```
The "C:/Projects/railsinstaller/stage/Ruby1.9.2/bin" directoty doesn´t exists, so I´he changed all bat files to the correct one, plus I´m on Win7, so the code shound´t be running after all. That wrong dir is RailsINstaller problem, but after correcting it, Aptana still doesn´t work.
```

The ruby/bin is in my PATH variable.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my response to this topic on RailsInstaller group:

https://groups.google.com/group/railsinstaller/msg/a0c2138948567b5b

Changing the shebang line of `rails` script (the extensionless one, not `rails.bat`) to:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
```

Should do the trick.

Also install gems with `--env-shebang` so `sh.exe` will be able to use the generated extensionless files.